# Saving information to Firebase Database and Storage

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have been trying to do this but something is wrong. So, the user should save the username, fullname and image to realtime database and storage in Firebase, but when I click the "save" button literally nothing happens. No toast messages are displaying,no progress dialog showing, the data does not go to Firebase. I don't know where the problem could be. Here is my code:

```
data class User(var userName: String ?= null, var fullName: String ?= null)
```

And here is the activity from where the user should put the data:

```
lass AccountSettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAccountSettingsBinding
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser
    private lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var storageReference: StorageReference
    private lateinit var imageUri: Uri


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityAccountSettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val uid = auth.currentUser?.uid
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
        val save = findViewById<Button>(R.id.save_btn)
        save.setOnClickListener {
            val userName = binding.usernameProfileFrag.text.toString()
            val fullName = binding.fullNameProfileFrag.text.toString()

            val user = User(userName, fullName)
            if (uid != null){
                databaseReference.child(uid).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful){
                    uploadProfilePic()
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this@AccountSettingsActivity, "Failed to update profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

     
    }

    private fun uploadProfilePic() {
        val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this@AccountSettingsActivity)
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading")
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait, this may take a while")
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/${R.drawable.profile}")
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Users/"+auth.currentUser?.uid)
        storageReference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener {

            progressDialog.show()
             Toast.makeText(this@AccountSettingsActivity, "Successfully uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }.addOnFailureListener{
            progressDialog.dismiss()
            Toast.makeText(this@AccountSettingsActivity, "Failed to upload the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are already logged into Firebase, aren't you?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Because uid is null. First you must enable auth / sing-in method / anonymous from firebase

```
        if (auth.currentUser == null) {
        auth.signInAnonymously().addOnSuccessListener {
            //created uid and do something
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            //error
        }
    } else {
        //you have a uid ! do something
    }
```

an advice, add uid variable to your user data class !